# How could I implement this listbox with WPF/DataBinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a working HTML form with a listbox from where the user can select from a list of standard bicycle tyre sizes. Each size maps internally to some numerical value, making the data source a Dictionary (map of key/value pairs).

The javascript implementation is as follows, and I would like to have the same behaviour in WPF with databinding (defining the dictionary/enum inside my domain-model class):

```
<select name="tiresize" id="tiresize"
    onchange="calcula();" style="width: 100px">
    <option value="305">26 X 1.0 (559 mm)</option>
    <option value="311">26 x 1 (650C)</option>
    <option value="312">26 X 1.5</option>
    <option value="324">26 X 1.9</option>
    <option value="330">26 X 1 3/8 (590 mm)</option>
    <option value="340">27 X 1</option>
    <option value="342">27 X 1 1/8</option>
    <option value="343">27 X 1 1/4</option>
    <option value="345">27 X 1 3/8</option>
    <option value="330">26 X 2.125</option>
    <option value="332">700 x 21</option>
    <option value="334" selected="selected">700 x 23</option>
    <option value="335">700 x 25</option>
    <option value="336">700 x 28</option>
    <option value="342">700 x 32</option>
    <option value="345">700 x 35</option>
    <option value="347">700 x 38</option>
    <option value="354">700 x 44</option>
    <option value="365">700 x 50</option>
    <option value="370">700 x 56</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set the DataContext of something (Window, Grid, etc.) that contains your ListBox to an instance of the class that contains the Dictionary. You can do this in XAML or in code. Then:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionaryProperty}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"
         SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding wheelRadius}"/>
```

As long as wheelRadius is of type `int` and has a public setter this will take the Value property of the `SelectedItem` (thanks to `SelectedValuePath`) and push that into `SelectedValue`, which will set your `wheelRadius` property through a `TwoWay Binding` (the default for `SelectedValue`, `SelectedItem`, and some others).

Comment: Could you detail this binding of a selected value to another model property? For example, there is the `wheelRadius` property in my model that should receive the `int` corresponding to the human-readable string key selected by the user. Sorry for n00bness...